# XeLaTeX: How to use Tex Gyre Pagella only outside math and how increase the height of its italic version

Tags: fonts, xetex

I would like to use the Tex Gyre Pagella font in my document but only outside the math environment. I have tried setting the math font as in the following code:

```latex
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[
    Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  Scale=MatchLowercase
  ]{texgyrepagella}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf} 

\begin{document}
This is some text that contains some \emph{italic text} and some \textbf{bold text} and some math: $x + y = z, \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{z}$.
\end{document}
```

However, the bold version of the math still uses Tex Gyre Pagella instead of computer modern.

[image]

For reference, this is how the math should be displayed in computer modern:

[image]

**How can tell `\setmainfont` to completely ignore everything inside the math environment?**

In addition, the italic version of Tex Gyre Pagella seems to have a lower height compared to the regular version (see the above screenshot). **Is it possible to scale the italic version to match the height of regular?**

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to mix Computer Modern math with Palatino. The problem with italics is the `Scale=MatchLowercase` instruction that should never be given for the main font.

Anyway, the solution is not to load `mathspec` that is incompatible with LuaLaTeX and also has problem with the more recent versions of `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}% not with unicode-math

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  ]{texgyrepagella}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\setmathrm{NewCM10-Regular.otf}[
  BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold.otf,
]
\begin{document}

This is some text that contains some \emph{italic text} and some \textbf{bold text}
and some math: $x + y = z, \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} = \mathrm{z}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find the output rather ugly, to be honest.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Great answer as always! What would be your recommendation for a math font to be used with Pagella please?

Comment: @f10w TeX Gyre Pagella Math, of course.

Comment: Haha, of course! Though my eyes still prefer CM...

Answer (score 0):

Using `mathspec` instead of `unicode-math` makes it work:

```latex
% \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathspec} %loads fontspec as well

\setmainfont[
    Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  Scale=MatchLowercase
  ]{texgyrepagella}
% \setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
```