Get all math symbols from MnSymnol colored "by default"
I'm experimenting with font pairing from Google fonts. For this I am using the mathspec package. In this case, I have placed the Manrope font as body text and math text accompanied by the MnSymbol package. The problem is that the math symbols in MnSymbol stand out more than the math font. I have tried to get around this drawback by coloring the symbols, but for a certain number of equations it would be quite laborious to color them one by one. Is it possible to have all the symbols in the MnSymbol package colored “by default”?
%!TEX program = Xelatex
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\Pra}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\Pra}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\Pra}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%fonts
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{griss}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont[Path=./fonts/Manrope/static/,
    UprightFont=*-Light.ttf,
    AutoFakeBold=1.2,
   AutoFakeSlant=0.15,
   ]{Manrope}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Path=./fonts/Manrope/static/,
    UprightFont=*-Light.ttf,
    AutoFakeBold=1.2,
    AutoFakeSlant=0.15,
    Color=000000
   ]{Manrope}

\newfontface\Pra{Prata-regular}[
     Path=./fonts/Prata/,
     Extension = .ttf,
     AutoFakeBold=1.2,
     AutoFakeSlant=0.15,
     %Contextuals=Swash
     ]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Prata}

Manrope Hello world \emph{HelloWorld}$Hello World$ $v\nu\delta$ 

\[\mathcolor{griss}{\int}_a^bf\mathcolor{griss}{(}x)\int_0^1f(x)\alpha\mathcolor{griss}{\partial}\pi\sum_0^{\infty}\mathcolor{griss}{\prod}_0^{\infty}\]
\end{document}


if I add
\everymath{\color{red}}
\everydisplay{\color{red}}

then I get

In this case, even the inline math has turned red, even when I add Color=000000 to the \sethamthfont options

First rule of asking questions: try to make your code compile with the least effort on the part of those you want help from ;). You answer questions, too, so what's the first thing you'd notice in your code? For me, it's the fonts. I've never heard of Manrope. I suspect (correctly) it is not in TeX Live. So I'm unlikely to be able to play with this without a lot of hassle. Given the focus is on MnSymbol, it seems unlikely that's essential so redo the question using something people already have.

Also, clarify if XeTeX is required or whether LuaTeX is an option.

I understand. I dared to ask the question due to the fact that Manrope is a Google font. I think I should have put that in. I noticed that MnSymbol's symbols have a higher weight than Manrope's and against that I can't do anything. That's why I thought of changing the color of all the MnSymbol symbols to make the use of Manrope with MnSymbol look more harmonized. And yes, XeTeX is required.

I'm afraid the answer here is probably that you shouldn't be doing this with or without the colour change. mathspec has issues with recent versions of fontspec (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713323/xelatex-how-to-use-tex-gyre-pagella-only-outside-math-and-how-increase-the-heig/713507#713507). Although that answer concerns LuaTeX, the problems with fontspec are probably relevant here, too, even though mathspec is not (presumably) incompatible with XeTeX. By the way mathspec has an option for MnSymbol. You don't need Manrope in your example.

As I understood things, mathspec was always intended to be transitional. It was written at a time when there were very few Unicode maths fonts and, of the few there were, even fewer were free. It was never a wholly satisfactory solution and I suspect it is not maintained because the need for it has more-or-less disappeared.

Well, my question was if I could color all the symbols in the MnSymbol package. I have achieved too much with \everymath{} \everydisplay{} I have edited the post showing what I got.
